# A short story about a theoretical parallel universe whose inhabitants find out that the universe is a simulation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've read a short story recently on the web. It was about a theoretical parallel universe which was filled with super intelligent humans. One day the inhabitants noticed that some of the stars started to flash like a lamp being switched on/off. They analyzed the situation and found out that they were living in a simulation which was run by extremely dumb aliens and this was an attempt form their part to communicate with the humans.

I'm looking for this story but google was not able to help me this time. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"That Alien Message" by Eliezer_Yudkowsky can be found here:

http://lesswrong.com/lw/qk/

Comment: Brilliant. Did you know it from the top of your head?

Comment: I read it a few years ago, and remembered enough extra details that I was able to google it.